# Get Click event on blank part of stage

Tags: php, kineticjs

I have stage inside I have 2 - 3 images.
I want to perform certain operation when I click in blank part of stage. But it will not execute when I click on Images inside stage.

I have tried this one but it will not stop image click here.

```
$(stage.getContent()).on('click', function(e) {

                // operation to perform ...

                });
```

Pl help me if anybody knows about this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to get image click then none perform else perform your action

Comment: Ok can you send me some code here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will catch *all clicks on the stage*, even clicks on image nodes.

One workaround is to fill the stage with an almost transparent background rectangle before any other nodes are added.

Then listen for clicks on that background rectangle.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Cx44H/

```
var bk=new Kinetic.Rect({
    x:0,y:0,
    width:stage.width(),
    height:stage.height(),
    opacity:.01,
    stroke:"white",
});
bk.on("click",function(){
    console.log("clicked on the background");
});
layer.add(bk);
```